SwiftData binding causes crash on close when a shape is focussed
Very strange issue I'm facing. I am finding that if I have a swiftUI control (such as a slider) with a binding to a property of a swiftData model (such as a Double), and have a separate focusable shape (such as a circle) in the view, then my app will crash with the error "SwiftData/BackingData.swift:124: Fatal error: Unable to get value - no backing Managed Object" if the circle is focussed when I quit the app
From what I can see the issue is that - if the shape is focussed - the slider attempts to access the bound property after the managed object has been closed. Weirdly this is even though there is no link between the control and the circle.
I've pasted below the code which I can get to cause this - you should experience it if you run this on a macOS 14.4.1 mac, click on the circle and then close the file
Note that this is based on the app being built as a document based app - wrapped in a DocumentGroup
Any ideas appreciated as this is driving me mad!
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class MyModel {
    
    init() {}

    var aValue: Double = 1.0
    
}

@MainActor
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @Query private var myModels:[MyModel]
        
    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            ForEach(myModels) {
                model in
                Slider(value: Bindable(model).aValue, in: 0...1)
                Circle().focusable()
                                
            }
        }.onAppear(){
            
            if self.myModels.count  == 0
            {
                let model = MyModel()
                modelContext.insert(model)
                try? modelContext.save()
                
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
}

As a note, if I add in a textField and move the focus to this after selecting the circle the app does not crash, so the issue seems to be with the fact that the Circle is focussed when the app closes

"...then close the file", what do you mean? I fail to reproduce this.

Thanks for looking - the steps to reproduce would be 1/ wrap the code above in boilerplate swiftData (DocumentGroup), 2/ Launch the app and click "new document", 3/ click on the white circle so it has focus, 4/ Quit the app either deleting or saving the changes

Ok, you should mention in the question that this is for a Document app. With that type of project I can reproduce.

thanks - done. Excuse my dim-ness but how else could I build this? I am pretty new to swiftUI and swiftData

Do you need a document based app in the first place, otherwise you can use a normal app. (If that is what you asked about)

I was looking at other options - a document based app is definitely the best for this use case. I think I can work around the problems by binding to a state variable and manually updating the model, but that seems ugly!

Maybe so but I think that is a good way to work around this issue
